# How can I download a single webpage to view completely offline in Linux?

Tags: curl, wget

I want to download some webpages completely off-line so I can review it later, Just single pages, not the whole website. However I can't find usable solution on the net.

I see some answers suggesting using the `wget -E -H -k -K -p url` command. But that didn’t solve the problem at all. Because it downloads many many pages from other site.

I’ve also tried the cURL command but the page is is not saved completely off-line, when opening it with Firefox, it keeps loading other addresses, so without an Internet connection it is not viewable.

I just want a single page to be offlined completely, so I can view it even the original website is down. take the sample page url as:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash
```

Comment: If there's JavaScript on the page that uses AJAX to load parts of the page later, there's no 100% solution.

Comment: but if you use the Firefox "save page as" , then select "web page, complete" , it actually do what I want to do, webpage displayed correctly, no need to connect to anything else. there is no way to do that? even call the help of some Browser ?

Comment: You can automate your browser, see for example [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox).

Answer (score 6):

Simply use:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p [url of the page you want to grab]
```

This comes directly from [the Wget man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options).

For example, just run that command on this page itself; running Wget version 1.18 on macOS 10.12.2 (Sierra):

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash
```

The files would be outputted into these directories:

[image: Screenshot of the Wget output.]

And this is the output of the command:

```
--2016-12-23 15:52:10--  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash
Resolving stackoverflow.com... 151.101.65.69, 151.101.193.69, 151.101.129.69, ...
Connecting to stackoverflow.com|151.101.65.69|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 253204 (247K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash.html'

stackoverflow.com/q 100%[===================>] 247.27K   466KB/s    in 0.5s    

2016-12-23 15:52:10 (466 KB/s) - 'stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash.html' saved [253204/253204]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2016-12-23 15:52:10--  https://cdn.sstatic.net/robots.txt
Resolving cdn.sstatic.net... 151.101.193.69, 151.101.65.69, 151.101.129.69, ...
Connecting to cdn.sstatic.net|151.101.193.69|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify cdn.sstatic.net's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to cdn.sstatic.net insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2016-12-23 15:52:10--  https://ajax.googleapis.com/robots.txt
Resolving ajax.googleapis.com... 172.217.6.202, 172.217.6.234, 172.217.7.10, ...
Connecting to ajax.googleapis.com|172.217.6.202|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify ajax.googleapis.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to ajax.googleapis.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2016-12-23 15:52:11--  https://ssum-sec.casalemedia.com/robots.txt
Resolving ssum-sec.casalemedia.com... 23.53.116.74
Connecting to ssum-sec.casalemedia.com|23.53.116.74|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify ssum-sec.casalemedia.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to ssum-sec.casalemedia.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2016-12-23 15:52:11--  https://i.stack.imgur.com/robots.txt
Resolving i.stack.imgur.com... 104.16.111.18, 104.16.108.18, 104.16.110.18, ...
Connecting to i.stack.imgur.com|104.16.111.18|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify i.stack.imgur.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to i.stack.imgur.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2016-12-23 15:52:11--  https://www.gravatar.com/robots.txt
Resolving www.gravatar.com... 192.0.73.2
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2016-12-23 15:52:11--  https://graph.facebook.com/robots.txt
Resolving graph.facebook.com... 31.13.73.1, 2a03:2880:f000:110:face:b00c::2
Connecting to graph.facebook.com|31.13.73.1|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify graph.facebook.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to graph.facebook.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2016-12-23 15:52:11--  https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/robots.txt
Resolving lh6.googleusercontent.com... 172.217.6.225, 2607:f8b0:4006:805::2001
Connecting to lh6.googleusercontent.com|172.217.6.225|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify lh6.googleusercontent.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to lh6.googleusercontent.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2016-12-23 15:52:11--  http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt
Reusing existing connection to stackoverflow.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2692 (2.6K) [text/plain]
Saving to: 'stackoverflow.com/robots.txt'

stackoverflow.com/r 100%[===================>]   2.63K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2016-12-23 15:52:11 (128 MB/s) - 'stackoverflow.com/robots.txt' saved [2692/2692]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2016-12-23 15:52:11--  http://pixel.quantserve.com/robots.txt
Resolving pixel.quantserve.com... 74.217.63.21, 74.217.63.57, 74.217.63.33, ...
Connecting to pixel.quantserve.com|74.217.63.21|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 26 [text/plain]
Saving to: 'pixel.quantserve.com/robots.txt'

pixel.quantserve.co 100%[===================>]      26  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2016-12-23 15:52:12 (1.03 MB/s) - 'pixel.quantserve.com/robots.txt' saved [26/26]

--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d
Connecting to cdn.sstatic.net|151.101.193.69|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify cdn.sstatic.net's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to cdn.sstatic.net insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
Connecting to ajax.googleapis.com|172.217.6.202|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify ajax.googleapis.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to ajax.googleapis.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=ed3b6e7707ad
Connecting to cdn.sstatic.net|151.101.193.69|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify cdn.sstatic.net's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to cdn.sstatic.net insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=b0ea75532e6d
Connecting to cdn.sstatic.net|151.101.193.69|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify cdn.sstatic.net's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to cdn.sstatic.net insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://ssum-sec.casalemedia.com/usermatch?s=183712&cb=https%3A%2F%2Fengine.adzerk.net%2Fudb%2F22%2Fsync%2Fi.gif%3FpartnerId%3D1%26userId%3D
Connecting to ssum-sec.casalemedia.com|23.53.116.74|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify ssum-sec.casalemedia.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to ssum-sec.casalemedia.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvLrx.jpg?s=32&g=1
Connecting to i.stack.imgur.com|104.16.111.18|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify i.stack.imgur.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to i.stack.imgur.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5432674c39c04589a00cb10c0a7620c1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNyBE.jpg?s=32&g=1
Connecting to i.stack.imgur.com|104.16.111.18|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify i.stack.imgur.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to i.stack.imgur.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/959ccd33301cb3c15953c1a632a36763?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a
Connecting to cdn.sstatic.net|151.101.193.69|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify cdn.sstatic.net's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to cdn.sstatic.net insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/01ba1d34ce5f61cb54f224f3c1df16e4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2c638d6bdc75ffd5dbf06a1053779104?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cc54ae5944af5810788795c32ebc815b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:12--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/902cdafbb7a8d060933e230fc8e3a488?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://graph.facebook.com/543512651/picture?type=large
Connecting to graph.facebook.com|31.13.73.1|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify graph.facebook.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to graph.facebook.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/18afb92b27771f65d19e50d390815ede?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/49cf5d5ff161eed26b99e75694299fe1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bf417f5e9252c2789103371b58db40c5?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/747ce6a2bd6c6a3de46786388f095e91?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6cb1b2c58abc2116f910ec9253ee387f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/baebdfebc624280c3f0dab895c0193ad?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8cad495bb49e7c9906290fee5dd60cb1?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b796380fa7643d02e9caeedce9d63427?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/695b15f15ed8500b23eee2985c1719e8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:13--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca0bf65459ea3fe592a9b5c61518b558?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:14--  https://i.stack.imgur.com/618FY.png?s=32&g=1
Connecting to i.stack.imgur.com|104.16.111.18|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify i.stack.imgur.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to i.stack.imgur.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:14--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/242a3a167a1a65837ae03c6641e8d42c?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:14--  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvxAu.png?s=32&g=1
Connecting to i.stack.imgur.com|104.16.111.18|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify i.stack.imgur.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to i.stack.imgur.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:14--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/df3976b028026148a7288a627849dd28?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:14--  https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3fa4.jpg?s=32&g=1
Connecting to i.stack.imgur.com|104.16.111.18|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify i.stack.imgur.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to i.stack.imgur.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:14--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a279c153f484f6d9656d41c41e82f45f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:14--  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMSLZ.png?s=32&g=1
Connecting to i.stack.imgur.com|104.16.111.18|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify i.stack.imgur.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to i.stack.imgur.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:14--  https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-TJzbxWxaOYg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAdE/fZy2Gb5BOMY/photo.jpg?sz=32
Connecting to lh6.googleusercontent.com|172.217.6.225|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify lh6.googleusercontent.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to lh6.googleusercontent.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:14--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/836f1754aff42d7eef28afb0c76f6a0e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2016-12-23 15:52:14--  https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4e4c3b5820f4f39c2bbe57a8823dd0ad?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
Connecting to www.gravatar.com|192.0.73.2|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.gravatar.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.gravatar.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
FINISHED --2016-12-23 15:52:14--
Total wall clock time: 4.6s
Downloaded: 3 files, 250K in 0.5s (471 KB/s)
Converting links in stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash.html... 34-300
Converted links in 1 files in 0.01 seconds.
```